# Making a node in Tkinter Treeview unselectable

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, tk-toolkit

I would like to know , how to make certain nodes in a Treeview object un-selectable, i.e. when clicked on such a node,the node shouldn't highlight.

I am working on
Python 3.3/2.7
Tkinter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a treeview with the option selectmode="none".
This turns off the default selection handling.

Give certain items a tag indicating that you want them to be "selectable".

Create a mouse-click binding on the widget and use the event-handler to set
the selection yourself.

```
def on_click(self, event):
    tree = event.widget
    item_name = tree.identify_row(event.y)
    if item_name:
        tags = tree.item(item_name, 'tags')
        if tags and (tags[0] == 'selectable'):
            tree.selection_set(item_name)
```